# ¿Cómo manipular la ejecución de eventos de varios controles en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

La idea es crear un gestor que nos permita almacenar el calendario anual de reservas de un camping en una grilla la cual tiene en sus fulas las habitaciones y en sus columnas los meses con los dias.

Para eso cree un calendario que contiene los dias de manera horizontal utilizando un UserControl que dentro tiene un TableLayoutPanel en tiempo de ejecución a esa tabla se le agrega otro UserControl que representa un rectángulo para cada celda (esta parte me gustaría simplificarla ya que estar creando varios UserControl disminuye el rendimiento.) la cuestión es que cuando creo los días a cada uno les agrego los eventos del MonthControl y uno de ellos es MouseDown, quiero hacer una seleccion clickeando en un día y arrastrando para hacer la reserva en ese rango de días pero cuando se ejecuta el evento de un DayBlank los demas no ejecutan su evento por más que sea el mismo que el del calendario. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: tienes que adjuntar el codigo (no en imagenes), explicar cual es el error. Te invito a leer [ask], recuerda que tambien debes subir un  [example]

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: y supongo tambien agregaste un evento mouse up a todos los controles???

Comment: Igual por lo general, para el usuario, es mas facil poner fecha de entrada, fecha de salida.. imagina tengo que ir por 12 dias y tengo que arrastrar exactamente desde aca hasta alla...

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Luego editar la pregunta.

Comment: Buenos dias!, gracias a todos por responder, si pienso lo mismo que gbianchi, pero el cliente asi lo quiere. De todas maneras voy a hacerlo como vos decis con datetimepicker y no me la complico ya que estoy corto de tiempo.

Para los que brindaron informacion de como preguntar, muchas gracias mi proxima pregunta sera mejor elaborada. Gracias por contestar, Saludos!